# Why is a question about a Drupal update.php warning message not related with Drupal?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

[How can I avoid a warning about the PHP mbstring extension?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11875/updating-module-php-mbstring-extension-warning-avoid-this-warning) was closed, and I disagree; this message appears when you try to update a module from update.php interface. And to be more clear, my question is about behavior of Drupal if is not installed that extension. I think that it's related with Drupal (please read the question).

Answer (score 1):

You don't install PHP extensions on Drupal 6; you install them on PHP. That is the reason why the question is off-topic on *Drupal Answer*. If the question can be asked from who is not using Drupal, it means the question is probably not about Drupal.

For example, some of those questions are not on-topic for *Drupal Answers*.

- What PHP version is compatible with Drupal 6? (It is about Drupal.)
- What is the equivalent for `hook_nodeapi()` in Drupal 7? (It is about Drupal.)
- How can I merge two arrays with PHP? (The same question could be asked from who is using Wordpress too.)

Comment: thanks @kiamlaluno for your answer. I try to ask about implications in Drupal for when is not possible install this PHP extension in Drupal 6 (please read again the question): the question is about experiences with Drupal for when is not used the extension: is possible avoid the extension? I mean, regarding implications in Drupal, the question is about Drupal behavior if this extension does not installed. the questions is not about good hosting, or howto install extensions. if some part of the question add noise, that part can be removed. but I think that is not necessary close it.

Answer (score 0):

It is directly related to the hosting environment, not the installation of Drupal. Someone flagged it as off topic, and I agreed.

Comment: I think that lots of questions in Drupal are related with Drupal, and also directly related with hosting, Mysql, PHP, or other technologies. for example http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/what-would-be-the-optimal-mysql-configuration-for-a-drupal-7-site

Comment: That answer was suggestions on how to optimize for Drupal. This is a warning from Drupal that you didn't configure your server properly.

Comment: then you give me the reason. is related with Drupal. how to optimize the hosting for Drupal.

Comment: There is a difference between optimizing a working install, and not being able to configure a server properly to get your install to stop erroring out.

Comment: I think that you are focusing in differences. To me is no clear why you can not see a valid question "try to being able to configure a hosting properly for Drupal", and you see a valid question "try to being able to configure a mysql properly for Drupal". I disagree, IMHO I think that you are wrong, but of course, you have the knowledge, I do not have it (this is why I make questions in DSE).

Comment: As a mod, I can't vote to close questions, because it will just close them. But I do respond with my best judgement to the votes to close of other users. I apologize if you disagree, and I hope you are able to find an answer to your problem.

Comment: also other users in drupal.org could need useful answers to these warning and other related with hosting topic http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=hosting

Comment: it might be OK to have this question on the site, provided it is not duplicated a million times elsewhere; see flowchart here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/